# How do I get the Status Line from a CloseableHttpResponse instance?

Tags: java, rest, http

I am trying to get the Status Line of an CloseableHttpResponse object, but I don´t know which Java class I have to use.

```
package com.mycompany.prueba_rest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;

public class Prueba_REST {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        //Crear objeto HttpClient.
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        //Crear un objeto HttpGet.
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://www.tutorialspoint.com");

        //Imprimir por pantalla el método usado.
        System.out.println("Request Type: "+httpget.getMethod());

        //Ejecutar el pedido GET.
        CloseableHttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(httpresponse.getEntity().getContent());
        
        //Imprimir la Línea de Estado.
                                        //Error!
        System.out.println(httpresponse.getStatusLine());
        while(scanner.hasNext()) System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
}
```

I tried looking in the official documentation, however, I didn´t find anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

The HttpClient5 `CloseableHttpResponse` doesn't have a method to retrieve the status line. The one from HttpClient4 does, but that's not compatible.

The HttpClient4 status line can give you three properties:

- `ProtocolVersion getProtocolVersion()`
- `int getStatusCode()`
- `String getReasonPhrase()`

You can get those directly from the classic `CloseableHttpResponse` with these methods:

- `ProtocolVersion getVersion()`
- `int getCode()`
- `String getReasonPhrase()`

Those are all defined by the `org.apache.hc.core5.http.HttpResponse` interface (the first through its super interface `HttpMessage`), so you can also get them from other `HttpResponse` implementations like `SimpleHttpResponse`.